# Can't get unserialized data

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

Actually I have inserted data into database applying `serialize()`. But when I try to fetch unserialized data it returns me only array. Below is my code.

```
<?php 
session_start();
include("admin/connection.php");
$keyData =  (string)$_GET['keyData'];
$route_table= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from route_plan WHERE vehicle = '".$keyData."'");

$fetched_data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($route_table);

$latitude=$fetched_data['latitude'];
$latitude=unserialize($latitude);
echo $latitude[0];
```

Let me tell you here I can get serialized data by the variable `$latitude;`

Comment: did you try using implode function in PHP?

Comment: Nope.       $latitude contains a:3:{i:0;s:11:"238.6755768";i:1;s:10:"237.654447";i:2;s:9:"237.86755";}.

I need this to be unserialized.

Comment: Use the same key which was used through which array was serialized

Comment: Key..I dint get you. will you please explain.
$latitude=$fetched_data['latitude']; 
Here $latitude contains the value I have inserted by serialization(given in above comment).All I need to convert that value applying unserialization and store in a variable.

Comment: please make sure that the data type of $latitude is of type string, check it using var_dump() function, then use unserialiaze() function.

Comment: Yes it is string.
string(71) "a:3:{i:0;s:11:"238.6755768";i:1;s:10:"237.654447";i:2;s:9:"237.86755";}"238.6755768

Answer (score 0):

if the array is like

```
<input type="text" name="input[]" value="">
```

and array is serialized and when you are going to display array is unserialized  and stored in $latitude

then to print you have to use

```
    latitude =unserialize($row['input']);
    $arrlength = count($latitude);
    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++)
   {
    echo $latitude[$x]; 
   }
```

Comment: Actually I am inserting a multiple latitude into database through serialize().How to get those multiple latitude data.